# Substract the price using Case in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case

I have 3 tables: training_schedules, training_discounts, and agents.
**training_schedules**: id, name, agent_id, price.
**training_discounts**: id, agent_id, schedule_id, discount.
**agents**: id, name

I try to subtract the **price** from training_schedules table with the **discount** column in training_discounts table like this:

```
SELECT ts.id, name, training_types, DATE_FORMAT(date_start ,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_start, 
                DATE_FORMAT(date_end ,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_end, quota, price, td.discount,
                CASE price WHEN td.agent_id = 2  THEN (price - td.discount) ELSE price END as total   
                FROM training_schedules ts
                LEFT JOIN training_discounts td on ts.id = td.schedule_id GROUP BY td.schedule_id;
```

But it doesn't right, the total column is still the same price as before even if agent_id is the same. What can possibly be wrong with my query? Here's the SQLfiddle if needed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd42d/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `group by` since you are not using any aggregation functions.

```
SELECT ts.id
  , name
  , training_types
  , DATE_FORMAT(date_start ,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_start
  , DATE_FORMAT(date_end ,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_end
  , quota, price
  , td.discount  
  , CASE WHEN td.agent_id = 2 THEN price - td.discount ELSE price END as total   
FROM training_schedules ts
LEFT JOIN training_discounts td on ts.id = td.schedule_id;
```

You are also using the `select case` wrongly. Another option is to use mysql `if()` function.

```
if(agent_id = 2, price - td.discount, price) as total
```

Comment: the total becomes incorrect. for example, price is 7.000,000 discount 1,000,000 the total suppose to be 6,000,000 but in your query total is 14,000,000

Comment: @Ying, try this new update